# Cannot INSERT INTO a PostgreSQL table, but I can UPDATE

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to Insert a new record in a PostgreSQL table, but I don't know why I'm not being successfully.

The syntax of the function is this:

```
def insertIP(ipx, stac, macx):
    hojenow = datetime.now()
    hoje = hojenow.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    bc = con.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO ip_comp (nome_comp, mac, ip_data, ip) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING id_ip"
    data = [stac, macx, hoje, ipx]
    bc.execute(sql,data)
    final = str(bclogon.fetchone()[0])
    con.commit()
    return final[0]
```

The result of this function is the exception as follows:

`Error name 'ip' is not defined`

The table above referenced is this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weblogon.ip_comp
(
    id_ip integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ip_comp_id_ip_seq'::regclass),
    ip character varying(15) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nome_comp character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    ip_data timestamp without time zone,
    mac character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT ip_comp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_ip),
    CONSTRAINT ip_comp_ip_key UNIQUE (ip)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

PS.: Even dropping UNIQUE Constraint from `ip` column, the exception persists.
The UPDATE operation runs fine.

```
    sql = "UPDATE ip_comp SET nome_comp=%s, mac=%s, ip_data=%s WHERE ip=%s RETURNING id_ip"
    data = [stac,macx,hoje,ipx]
    bclogon.execute(sql,data)
```

Comment: What does `{ipx = '172.24.12.35', stac = 'SALES', macx = '080027342A17' e.g}` mean at the end of the `def` line?

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: I don't think that's a PostGres error. I think it's a Python message referring to a variable named `ip`.

Comment: `{ipx = '172.24.12.35', stac = 'SALES', macx = '080027342A17' e.g}` is an example of parameters passed to the function. The entire code is posted Here:[https://gist.github.com/redbob365/84bce38a4ae4737e29cbbe84ec415285#file-gistfile1-txt]

Comment: Examples should be in comments, or in text outside the code block.

Comment: We still need the full traceback to see where the error is happening.

Comment: I think the error comes from this line: `print("Inseri IP="+ip+" em "+ comp +" sob id "+final)` You never defined the variables `ip` or `comp`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the SQL.

Comment: In another function you have `print("Aatualizei IP="+ipx+" em "+ estax +" sob id "+final)`. That's probably what you want here, too.

Comment: The output of the function is posted here: [https://gist.github.com/redbob365/66b45e55c51c844358d1d91d505278e6#file-gistfile2-txt]

Comment: Get rid of your `try/except`. It makes it difficult to see the real error, because it doesn't show the traceback. Or put it only around the SQL, not the entire function body. It's catching errors unrelated to the SQL.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar, we found the error. In fact, I declared column names at the output, not the variables.

Comment: This is why you need to put the real code in the question. The problem is unrelated to the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Bamar for the notation!

The second line below had an error

```
final = str(bclogon.fetchone()[0])
print("Inseri IP="+ip+" em "+ estax +" sob id "+final)
```

because the variable `ip` was not defined. The correct variable was `ipx`